# How do i find the best encoding of a string from a table of text strings in pseudopolynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Problem:**

> Consider the following data compression technique. We have a table of
> m text strings, each at most k in length. We want to encode a data
> string D of length n using as few text strings as possible. For
> example, if our table contains (a,ba,abab,b) and the data string is
> bababbaababa, the best way to encode it is (b,abab,ba,abab,a)—a total
> of five code words. Give an O(nmk) algorithm to find the length of the
> best encoding. You may assume that every string has at least one
> encoding in terms of the table.

I found this problem in skiena's Algorithm design manual book and tried to solve it.

My best guess is to match all possible substrings of the string (D) with all texts in the table of length (m), Time complexity: `O(n*n*k*m)`.

Is there any better way to approach this problem in `O(nmk)` pseudopolynomial time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstand, but it sounds like your solution would have a larger time complexity than O(nnkm).

To generate a list of all possible partitions of D that contain all elements of D would take O(nn). Then, for each subset in each partition (of which there are a maximum of n subsets), you would need to validate that a match in the table is present which would take O(km) for each subset. After n*n possible partitions (not actually n*n, but the Bell number of n), matching a maximum of n sets each would get a complexity of O(nnnmk)

That said, I think there is a faster way to do it by attempting to construct a tree.

Starting at the beginning of D, you can attempt to match all strings in the table. Each string in the table represents a branch, and if the table string does not match D at the first position, then the branch terminates. If it does match, then the process repeats starting at the end of the table string that was just matched.

A trick with this method is that you only need to keep the series of matches that yield unique lengths. Repeating this process in a breadth-first manner means that if a set of table strings that reaches a specific length has already been discovered, any sets of table strings that reach that length again are guaranteed to contain either the same number or more strings from the table but still match the same substring of D. For example, the table strings {abab, ab} will both yield the string 'abab' with a length of 4, but one of them will match on the first iteration and one will match on the second. In this example, an encoding that contains 'ab'+'ab' will always be worse than an encoding that contains 'abab' in its place, so we discard the 'ab'+'ab' encoding. A simple O(1) lookup table can be used to check this, and any lengths that have been seen before can have their branches terminated as well. For this reason, there are a maximum of n unique lengths that can be discovered, each only discoverable a single time, meaning there are a maximum of n possible branches.

The strings in the table still must each be checked, which is still O(mk). Adding in the branching, *I believe* this yields a complexity of O(nmk), since at most n branches are created.

For an example, the table {a, aa} on the string 'aaaaaa' will contain 2 branches per iteration for 3 iterations. Each branch takes O(mk) to check, so this example has a time complexity of O(nmk).

EDIT: Since there is some skepticism about my proposed implementation, I've implemented it in C and done some analysis.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* alphabet = "abcdef";
const int alphabetLen = strlen(alphabet);

void printTable(char** table, int k){
    printf("Table: {%s", table[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<k; i++){
        printf(", %s", table[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

char** generateTable(int k, int m){

    char** table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*k);
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        int tableStringLen = (rand() % (m-1)) + 1;
        table[i] = (char*)malloc(tableStringLen+1);
        for(int j=0; j<tableStringLen; j++){
            table[i][j] = alphabet[rand() % alphabetLen];
        }
        table[i][tableStringLen] = 0;
    }

    return table;
}

// Unfortunately, the length of the string is partially determined by the size of m
// it's done this way to avoid generating a random string and ensuring the table can encode it
char* generateString(char** table, int k, int m){
    int minLength = rand()%200 + m*2;
    char* string = (char*)malloc(minLength + m);

    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; j<minLength; i++){
        int tableStringIndex = rand() % k;
        strcpy(string+j, table[tableStringIndex]);
        j += strlen(table[tableStringIndex]);
    }
    string[j] = 0;

    return string;
}

void printSolution(char* string, int* branchLengths, int n){
    if(!n){ return; }
    printSolution(string, branchLengths, branchLengths[n]);
    printf("%.*s ", n-branchLengths[n], string+branchLengths[n]);
}

int* solve(char* string, char** table, int n, int m, int k, int* comparisons){
    int* currentBranchEnds = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), n); // keeps track of all of the current ends
    int currentBranchCount = 1; // keeps track of how many active branch ends there are

    int* newBranchEnds = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), n); // keeps track of the new branches on each iteration
    int newBranchCount = 0;

    int* branchLengths = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), (n+1)); // used to reconstruct the solution in the end

    // used for O(1) length lookups
    int* tableStringLengths = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k);
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){ tableStringLengths[i] = strlen(table[i]); }

    *comparisons = 0;

    // continue searching while the entire string hasn't been encoded
    while(!branchLengths[n]){

        // for every active branch
        for(int i=0; i<currentBranchCount; i++){


            // try all table strings
            for(int j=0; j<k; j++){
                int newBranchEnd = currentBranchEnds[i] + tableStringLengths[j];
                
                // if the new length (branch end) already exists OR
                // if the new branch would be too long for the string, discard the branch
                *comparisons += 1;
                if(newBranchEnd > n || branchLengths[newBranchEnd]){ continue; }

                // check to see if the table string matches the target string at this position
                // could be done with strcmp, but is done in a loop here to be explicit about complexity
                char match = 1;
                for(int l=0; table[j][l]; l++){
                    *comparisons += 1;
                    if(string[currentBranchEnds[i] + l] != table[j][l]){
                        match = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // if it matches, we can create a new branch at this position
                *comparisons += 1;
                if(match){
                    branchLengths[newBranchEnd] = currentBranchEnds[i];
                    newBranchEnds[newBranchCount] = newBranchEnd;
                    newBranchCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // swap the branch ends arrays to save copying
        int* tmp = currentBranchEnds;
        currentBranchEnds = newBranchEnds;
        newBranchEnds = tmp;

        currentBranchCount = newBranchCount;
        newBranchCount = 0;
    }

    free(currentBranchEnds);
    free(newBranchEnds);
    free(tableStringLengths);

    return branchLengths;
}

int main(){
    int k = rand() % 30 + 2;
    int m = rand() % 15 + 2;

    char** table = generateTable(k, m);
    printTable(table, k);

    char* string = generateString(table, k, m);
    int n = strlen(string);
    printf("String: %s\n", string);

    int comparisons;
    int* solution = solve(string, table, n, m, k, &comparisons);
    printf("Solution: ");
    printSolution(string, solution, n);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Comparisons: %d\n", comparisons);

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){ free(table[i]); }
    free(table);
    free(solution);
    free(string);
}
```

The analysis was generated by running the algorithm >500000 times on randomly generated values  of n, m, and k. The number of "comparisons" was incremented at every `if` statement, as seen in the code, and the average number of comparisons per value of n, m, and k is graphed.

[image: Complexity Analysis]

There is clearly a linear relationship between the number of comparisons (as calculated) and the size of n, m, and k. This shows the complexity is O(nmk)

Comment: I implemented your algorithm in python (see my answer) and sadly my code looks like O(n^2 m k). Please do tell me if you find that my implementation can be optimized, or if you disagree with my analysis.

Comment: if you would include code that compiles that would help in analysis..., overall there is no need for tree - IMHO my code solves problem in given complexity, but tree surely improves performance although not asymptotic performance

Comment: @quester Apologies for the non-compiling code; there was an extra line leftover from analysis. While I was visualizing my solution as a tree, in implementation it ends up being quite similar to your solution. In fact, I think they're exactly the same in principle.

Answer (score 2):

We can incrementally, for each prefix of the sentence, construct a solution with minimal number of cuts by trying to append a word to a prefix of smaller size.

```
words = {'ba', 'a', 'abab', 'b'}
sentence = 'bababbaababa'

def smallest_cut(sentence, words):
    max_word_length = max(len(w) for w in words)
    words_by_length = [[] for i in range(max_word_length + 1)]
    for w in words:
        words_by_length[len(w)].append(w)

    results_by_length = dict()
    results_by_length[0] = []

    for i in range(len(sentence) + 1):
        for j in range(max(0, i-max_word_length), i):
            if j in results_by_length:
                for w in words_by_length[i-j]:
                    if sentence[j:i] == w:
                        if i not in results_by_length or len(results_by_length[j]) + 1 < len(results_by_length[i]):
                            results_by_length[i] = results_by_length[j] + [w]

    return results_by_length[len(sentence)]

print(smallest_cut(sentence, words))
```

The first `for` loop is `n` iterations, the second and third combined are `m` iterations, the comparison `sentence[j:i] == w` is `k` operations.

Comment: I copied the first two lines of your code, yes. The explanation is obvious; the first loop buckets the words by length, the second goes through that bucket

Comment: @Stef I also changed *my* original variable names to yours for comparability/consistency across the solutions and am considering adopting your function name as well. Should I acknowledge that, too?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode You just did, didn't you ;)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode As I said, I normally don't mind at all; and I do agree that answers are easier to read if they follow the same conventions than if everyone is coming up for different names for the same things. But blatantly copying another answer and then literally writing "this problem is too simple for me so I didn't read the other answers" in the post was crossing a line.

Comment: @Stef I've read both of your solutions now. There's no plagiarism (not counting the input data and function signature). Your solutions are quite different. Yours [isn't even correct](https://tio.run/##fZHRaoMwGIXvfYpzZ0JLO9jNKPgKewERic3vFqq/kqSzo/TZXdJq6zoYQsST75zzx/Tf/rPj17fejuPQWe2Q4ZxWKl0jvS2VquK7Si@JI/bEewpMQMJTqbiqNEk01XCtahpyvtwfvZjZNa6xcpcAOoa/7JAXl/DVqlNpPFnlTcextyG@2yS2W7SGRRQHibqzGGB4Sgv2qJRRsYo/SPxOu9bhyXXTwhjlsdfKx2OcL5MWSXFYo7dUm5OMHr0Jea0TcvYBpsZhNU3Enb9SUKwxj50fdjNQIMswPLyP3nyBIB8KrKbaBbtsyp5@zTITsOSPltEY54WlL7KOtPhbJeV8@s1t687EjSnkvWNKkt4aDhf4323KcfwB) (look under "Output").

Comment: @Stef Oh, interesting. I thought tio.run encodes the output in the link. But apparently it stores it on their server and shows the output of the latest run. If it shows a correct result (5 words) then run it a few times until you get a wrong result (6 words). You depend on the iteration order of the set, which changes from run to run due to string hash randomization.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I was resetting `d_update` in the wrong loop. Now it should work - [tio link](https://tio.run/##fZHRaoMwGIXvfYpzZ0JLO9jNKPgKewERic3vFqq/kqSzo/TZXdJq6zoYQsST75zzx/Tf/rPj17fejuPQWe2Q4ZxWKl0jvS2VquK7Si@JI/bEewpMQMJTqbiqNEk01XCtahpyvtwfvZjZNa6xcpcAOoa/7JAXl/DVqlNpPFnlTcextyG@2yS2W7SGRRQHibqzGGB4Sgv2qJRRsYo/SPxOu9bhyXXTwhjlsdfKx2OcL5MWSXFYo7dUm5OMHr0Jea0TcvYBpsZhNU3Enb9SUKwxj50fdjNQIMswPLyP3nyBIB8KrKbaBbtsyp5@zTITsOSPltEY54WlL7KOtPhbJeV8@s1t687EjSnkvWNKkt4aDhf4323KcfwB)

Comment: @Sopel  I can't take back the downvote unless the answer is edited. You could for instance, edit the snarky comment out ;)

Comment: @Stef Or they could improve their complexity with `w = sentence[j:i]` and checking `if w in words_by_length[i-j]:` (the latter should be made a set). I think that's O((n+m)k) then.

Comment: @Stef You posted the same link as mine. Need to generate a new one after editing. Now [gets all permutations right](https://tio.run/##fVLRaoMwFH3PV9y3JLS0gzEYBX9hPyBFol63rCaRJM6O0m93SdTWbjCEiOeee869x3Tf/sPo59fOjuNgbO0ggwstBd0CnY5SlPFd0itxqD3qCgMnUMJTingKSkiNDTgl2hadL6res4W7hSTLDwSgjuJPB8iP1/ClxLmQHq3w0ujo26K@tXHY70FJzSI4cGiMhQGkntVCe0SKiFih35E9qiW7YFj0XS18HPhyTcijzsSaUHbaQmexkWce6/UuqCnH@MIBkA2cNvM82vjEAqFrWIbOT4eFcIQsg@Hee58lX1EgH46wmW1X3LVT9iuYtSaARd9bDa10nln8QuuwZn@tOJ/y2E2FGyPCs8Sb0UhIY42CmKM3pnUgVWeshw6t6v0ULUkRpqsSAlhX2P1PR1XXtz6s@O@tSFThXPBLW05daemXFC2lu08jHwqLBums1J5R11cVOkf5OP4A), ...

Comment: ... at least for this test case.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode indeed, that would be a [big] improvement.

Comment: Actually those buckets don't even make sense then anymore, could just check `if w in words:` (that's even already a set).

Comment: *"I think that's O((n+m)k) then"* - Oops, I thought wrong. Creating the slices `[j:i]` for lengths 1 to k would of course take k^2. On the other hand, m wouldn't play a role anymore. So I think it would be O(nk^2). Could be better or worse than O(nmk), depends on the input. But since the task asks for O(nmk)...

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode you only have to consider the slices of lengths that appear in the words, so `k<=m` here. But there are better algorithms for finding matches against multiple strings, though it would get more complicated

Comment: Not really `k<=m` (since those are "defined" by the input, not by what we do with it), but you're right, the number of realistic slices is limited by m as well. So... O(nk min(m,k))?

Comment: @Sopel I'd like to apologize for my short-tempered comments two days ago.

Answer (score 1):

O(nmk) solution

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Set

def smallest_cut(sentence: str, words: Set[str]) -> int:
    lookup = [1e10 for i in range(len(sentence)+1)]
    step_results = defaultdict(set)
    step_results[0].add(sentence)
    curr_step = 1
    while step_results[curr_step-1]: # this line and next line has in fact O(n) because of 'lookup'
        for curr_sentence in step_results[curr_step-1]: # look to comment above
            for word in words: # O(m)
                if curr_sentence.startswith(word): # O(k)
                    new_sentence = curr_sentence[len(word):]  # remove prefix
                    if new_sentence:
                        if lookup[len(new_sentence)] > curr_step:
                            lookup[len(new_sentence)] = curr_step  # cheat with lookup for O(1) complexity instead O(log(n))
                            step_results[curr_step].add(new_sentence)
                    else: # we found shotrest encoding
                        return curr_step
        curr_step += 1

smallest_cut('bababbaababa', {'ba', 'a', 'abab', 'b'})
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with an explanation? I have several questions when reading your code. The most important question is: How is your code fundamentally different than mine? It looks to me as if you just took my code and replaced `dict` with `defaultdict` and `set` with `typing.Set`, and replaced `for _ in range(max_iterations):` with `while True:`. How do you conclude that your code is O(n m k)??

Comment: please look on new version, one thing that can be improved is to cut prefixes with use of trie, additionally lines `while` and another has complexity `O(n)` because `steps_results` will hold max `n` sentences because trick with `lookup` ensures it

Comment: try this on your solutions `print(smallest_cut('bababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbbababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbbababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbbababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaabababababbaababababab', {'a', 'b', 'abab', 'ba'}))
` 216

Comment: @Stef it's funny how we are arguing/fighting who is right and OP is sitting in the back and watches with laughs :)

Comment: I'm asking more than arguing - obviously there is something inefficient about my code if it's *n^2 m k* instead of *n m k*. Thanks for the test case, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization solution in Python. `solve(i)` computes the result for the first i letters, so the answer is `solve(n)`. For every prefix length `i`, try all words as possible suffix of that prefix.

O(nmk) since there are n possible `i` arguments, each checks m words, and each word check costs up to k letter checks.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5BasQwDLz7FbrZommh9FIKC31Bv1DsRCYCRwq202Vfn41NSg9tdRghaTQz663OKi@va973mHWBuMlYVVMBXlbNFVLePkc/zmTMVfNU4ALW2wFs6OiDD32yppBUkpEaI7R98A29Neb9R2WiCEXTFznGNwNHZapbFmDwMsHC4tx5h0dIJK7ZIsIDPHf674qaoZGApffyD48P5zPjE8lUrlznrj7AhwoNwIjD379Har@leolJfXWWJVpEY9bMUs@4Leq3PCLu@x0)

```
from functools import lru_cache

words = 'a', 'ba', 'abab', 'b'
sentence = 'bababbaababa'

@lru_cache
def solve(i):
    return i and min((solve(i - len(word)) + 1
                      for word in words
                      if sentence.endswith(word, None, i)),
                     default=float('inf'))

print(solve(len(sentence)))
```